# how to parse this particular json in swift

Tags: json, swift, ios8, swifty-json

I am new to Swift and JSON, so please bear with me if this is stupid. I am trying to parse this particular JSON http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users in swift. I am able to get the values of one user by typing http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1 , but the problem is, it only provides me the values for one user at a time. I am looking for a way to get the values of all the users in one go.

I am using the SwiftyJSON API.

This is the code that I have been using:

```
//  RestApiManager.swift


 import Foundation

 typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void
 class RestApiManager: NSObject{

 static let sharedInstance = RestApiManager()

let baseURL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"

func getUser(onCompletion: (JSON) ->Void){
    makeHTTPGetRequest(baseURL, onCompletion: {json, err -> Void in onCompletion(json)})
}


func makeHTTPGetRequest(path: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        let json:JSON = JSON(data: data)
        onCompletion(json, error)
    })
    task.resume()

}
}
```

This is my MasterViewController.swift class

```
//
//  MasterViewController.swift
//
//
import UIKit
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
var objects = [AnyObject]()


 var contactsData = NSMutableArray()   //array that will hold all the contact details.


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    getContactListJSON()

}

func getContactListJSON(){

        RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getUser { json -> Void in
        let user: AnyObject = json["id"].object
        self.contactsData.addObject(user)
        println(self.contactsData)
   }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - Table View
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contactsData.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell


    return cell

}   

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is very very simple. Just do something like this and it will work:

```
func getContactListJSON(){
    let urlString = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    let urlEncodedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let url = NSURL( string: urlEncodedString!)
    var task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, innerError) in
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        let contactsArray = json.arrayValue

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            for contacts in contactsArray
            {
                let id = contacts["id"].stringValue
                let name = contacts["name"].stringValue
                println( "id: \(id) name: \(name)" )
            }
        })
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I in doubt swiftyJSON has some info [here](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/master/Example#usage)

Comment: PS if the "id" is always an int you could also do: let id = contacts["id"].intValue

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works just fine! Just one more question in my mind, what happens if let's id is nil ?

Comment: Hi. Then the value will be nil. You should actually do something like this: var id:String? if let id = contacts["id"].stringValue {  //do something with id } else { do something else or nothing } If you think the answer is correct, pls mark my post as answer and vote up ny one. Thanks a lot

Comment: I am new to swift and JSON, I am having some errors when I try to populate the table with the values. Could you please help me with that too ? Thanks!

Comment: That's fine, I figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of how to parse the json array you listed above. Note that this does not check properly all the cases of the json value being nil. So, use optional check to ensure that it does not crash.

```
class Geolocation {
    var latitude: String!
    var longitude: String!
}

class Company: Printable {
    var name: String!
    var bs: String!
    var catchPhrase: String!

    var description: String {
        get {
            return "\(name), catchPhrase: \(catchPhrase)"
        }
    }
}

class Address: Printable {

    var description: String {
        return "City: \(city), Street: \(street), suite: \(suite), zipCode: \(zipCode), geocode: \(geocode)"
    }
    var city: String!
    var street: String!
    var suite: String!
    var zipCode: String!

    var geocode: Geolocation!
}

class Person: Printable {

    var description: String {
        get {
            return "identifier: \(identifier) name:\(name) email:\(email) phone:\(phone) username:\(userName) website:\(website)\n Company: \(company), Address: \(address)"
        }
    }

    var identifier: Int!
    var name: String!
    var email: String!
    var phone: String!
    var userName: String!
    var website: String!

    var company: Company!
    var address: Address!


}


func createCompany(companyDict: NSDictionary) -> Company {
    let company = Company()
    company.name = companyDict["name"] as! String
    company.catchPhrase = companyDict["catchPhrase"] as! String
    company.bs = companyDict["bs"] as! String
    return company
}

func createGeolocation(geoDict: NSDictionary) -> Geolocation {
   let geo = Geolocation()
   geo.latitude = geoDict["lat"] as? String
   geo.longitude = geoDict["lng"] as? String
   return geo
}


func createAddress(addressDict: NSDictionary) -> Address {
    let address = Address()
    address.street = addressDict["street"] as? String
    address.suite = addressDict["suite"] as? String
    address.city = addressDict["city"] as? String
    address.zipCode = addressDict["zipCode"] as? String
    address.geocode = createGeolocation(addressDict["geo"] as! NSDictionary)
    return address
}


func createPerson(personDict: NSDictionary) -> Person {
    let person = Person()

    if let identifier = personDict["id"] as? Int {
        person.identifier = identifier
    }

    if let name = personDict["name"] as? String {
        person.name = name
    }

    if let email = personDict["email"] as? String {
        person.email = email
    }

    if let phone = personDict["phone"] as? String {
        person.phone = phone
    }

    if let username = personDict["username"] as? String {
        person.userName = username
    }

    if let website = personDict["website"] as? String {
        person.website = website
    }

    person.company = createCompany(personDict["company"] as! NSDictionary)
    person.address = createAddress(personDict["address"] as! NSDictionary)
    return person
}



let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: "/Users/Jackson/Desktop/MyPlayground.playground/Resources/test.json")
let json: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .allZeros, error: nil)

var personArray = [Person]()

for dict in json as! NSArray {

    if let personDict = dict as? NSDictionary {
            personArray += [createPerson(personDict)]
    }
}

println(personArray)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help! But with this implementation we will have to check all the cases of the json value being nil. Is there a way to get it done with the code that I am using ?

Comment: Instead of creating the model person, just use the same NSArray to populate the tableview, that should be quite straightforward.

Comment: I meant is there a way doing it using SwiftyJSON?